# How to handle 2 versions of Python on same client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I use ArcGIS 10.3 at work and it comes with Python 2.7.8; so when I run any of the .py/.pyc/.pyw files, it defaults to the path leading that versions .exe file.

Because of some non-ArcGIS related work, we are also being provisioned Python 3.4.2, which also installed its own path.

The question begs, how do I tell each .py/.pyc/.pyw file which Python (and associated IDLE [we don't get any IDE at work]) to execute the script with?

Comment: Use a shebang. What shebang you use depends on your OS, although in theory linux-style shebangs should work on all OS's. On windows, you will need to associate python files with 'py.exe' which will read the shebang and run the appropriate version of python. [More info here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).

Comment: You can use shebang lines (lines starting with `#!`) on Windows.as well as Unix/Linux. It's included in Python 3.x. See subsection titled [**Shebang Lines**](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#shebang-lines) of the [**Using Python on Windows**](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#using-python-on-windows) section of the documentation. This is done with something called `pylauncher` which can also be [downloaded](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/overview) separately for Python 2.x only installations (where it's not included). You end up with a `py.exe` to use.

Comment: BTW, I've been using Python for many years without an IDE. I have a fairly decent text editor which allows me to configure it to execute the current file with whatever program I want (and optionally capture the output it produces). The point being, stop feeling sorry for yourself. `;-)`

Comment: @Martineau we don't have availability to download `pylauncher` for 2.x, so when 3.x gets installed, on a Windows OS, in my scripts that need to run in 3.x, I would put `#! C:\Path\To\python.exe`. Since I wont have a launcher for 2.x, how would you recommend pointing those scripts that require 2.x towards its `python.exe`?

Comment: @Jonathan Same question to you as I posted to Martineau above

Comment: pstatix: There aren't different versions of pylauncher for Python 2 & 3. If you have Python 3.x installed it should already be installed. Try running `py.exe` from the command line to verify. Also, you **don't** put something like `#! C:\Path\To\python.exe` in your files, you just put `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. Please read some of the fine documentation I linked to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyenv is an excellent choice.

Particularly, set pyenv local and along with virtualenv, you get whatever you need on a per-project basis.

https://amaral.northwestern.edu/resources/guides/pyenv-tutorial